# Facebook Ads: how to create a pixel custom Javascript event to detect a click on a Youtube video

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube, facebook-ads-api, youtube-iframe-api

Let's say we have the Youtube embedded code:

```
<iframe id="my-youtube-video-id" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tzbrKBv-khE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And the Facebook pixel event code:

```
<button id="addToCartButton">Purchase</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#$my-youtube-video-id').click(function() {
fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to detect when somebody clicks the video. I'm on WordPress. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

PS: I'm following the documentation on: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/402791146561655?id=1205376682832142 and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation/conversion-tracking

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue with Facebook Events as much as it is an issue with the iFrame. The url hosted within the iFrame receives the click event, and does not bubble that event up through to the iFrame element itself. Luckily with youtube videos you can use the Embedded player API to perform actions based on the player's state. Try this:

```html
<iframe id="my-youtube-video-id" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tzbrKBv-khE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script>
  // This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('my-youtube-video-id', {
        events: {
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    }

    var done;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event){
      if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        //Here is where you can add your event, we also use the done variable to make sure the event will only fire once.
        fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
        done = true;
      }
    }

  </script>
```

EDIT: See this jsFiddle which will  [log to console when the `onPlayerStateChange()` function is called](https://jsfiddle.net/v1cr08je/13/)